# Returning Powers of a Two-Variable Polynomial as a Vector in PARI/GP?

Tags: vector, polynomials, pari, pari-gp

I'm trying to view the monomials of a two-variable polynomial in vector form. So, for example, if I input `x^2 + x^3*y + x*y + y^2 + 1`, I would like to view it as `[[2;0], [3;1], [1;1], [0;2], [0;0]]` - a vector made of column vectors.

If I use `Vec` on a two-variable polynomial, it simply treats the second variable as a number, giving `Vec( x^2 + x^3*y + x*y + y^2 + 1 ) = [ y, 1, y, y^2 + 1 ]`, which I don't think can then be twisted into something that would work for me.

Any ideas on how this might be able to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to calc all the monomials by your own. Your bivariate polynomial can be viewed as the univariate polynomial having polynomial coefficients. Firstly, you select the primary variable (e.g. `'x`) and find its exponents together with its nonzero coefficients:

```
exponents(f, v=variable(f)) = {
    if(type(f) != "t_POL",
        return([[0, f]])
    );
    my(x = varhigher("#"));
    my(coeffs = Vecrev(subst(f, v, x)));
    my(indexes = select((c) -> c != 0, coeffs, 1));

    [[n-1, coeffs[n]] | n <- Vec(indexes)]
};

exponents(1)
> [[0, 1]]
exponents(x^2 + x^3*y + x*y + y^2 + 1)
> [[0, y^2 + 1], [1, y], [2, 1], [3, y]]
exponents(x^2 + x^3*y + x*y + y^2 + 1, 'y)
> [[0, x^2 + 1], [1, x^3 + x], [2, 1]]
```

Secondly, given such list of exponents and coefficients you easily obtain the complete list of monomials:

```
monomial_list(f) = {
    concat(
        apply(
            (xs) -> [[xs[1], p[1]] | p <- exponents(xs[2])],
            exponents(f)
        )
    )
};

monomial_list(0)
> [[0, 0]]
monomial_list(x^2 + x^3*y + x*y + y^2 + 1)
> [[0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0], [3, 1]]
```